# NgIf-Else condition does not work properly

Tags: typescript, angular8, angular-ng-if

I'm a beginner on Angular 8 and I've some difficulties about a part of my code.
Indeed, I'm trying using the ngIf Else condition in a  to display a button according to the value I retrieve.

```html
<div class="form-group">  
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="input-group col-12 md-12">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label for="situation" class="input-group-text">Current Situation</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="situation" formControlName="situation" name="situation" [(ngModel)]="employed">
                <option value="employed" name="employed">Employed(including unpaid family workers and apprentices)</option>
                <option value="employed" name="employed">Employed but is temporarily absent(leave without pay, parental leave etc.)</option>
                <option value="unemployed"> Unemployed, looking for work(job seekers)</option>
                <option value="retired"> Retired </ option >
                <option value="unable">Unable to work(disability)</option>
                <option value="domesticWorker"> Woman or man working in their own household(domestic worker)</option>
                <option value="student"> Pupil or Student</option>
                <option value="preschool"> Pre - school child</option>
                <option value="other"> Other(specify) </ option >
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="employed; then trueCondition else elseTemplate" >
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#householdsFormModal2" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                data-dismiss="modal" type="button"
                [disabled]="householderForm.invalid">SUBMIT</button> 
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

When I'm choosing the first two option, my button is setting to Next but, when I'm choosing other options it staying to Next state instead of Submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ngIfThen` syntax which requires `trueCondition` to be a template as well.

See the [Angular NgIf documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description).

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="employed == 'employed'; then trueCondition else elseTemplate"></ng-container>
<ng-template #trueCondition>
    <!-- Content if true -->
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <!-- Content if false -->
</ng-template>
```

What I think you want is the `ngIf` syntax, which is `*ngIf="employed == 'employed'; else elseTemplate`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="employed == 'employed'; else elseTemplate">
    <!-- Content if true -->
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <!-- Content if false -->
</ng-template>
```

Also, be careful to not confuse your `ngModel` named `employed` with its actual value that can be a `string` with the value `employed`.

The `ngModel` named `employed` will always be "truthy", so make sure to check `employed == 'employed'`.